# Полное блокирование Windows

Tags: c++, c, winapi, драйвер

Есть задача разработать софт, который полностью блокирует рабочую станцию, показывая уведомление. Не должны работать никакие <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> и т. д., и фокус должен быть на окне. Пользователь читает уведомление, и после окно закрывается. User32 подтупляет, и не совсем удобно.

Есть какие-то способы, как, например, работают антивирусы? Как работает UAC? В какую сторону копать? Стоит требование, чтобы приложение работало на любой Windows. Без библиотек Windows путь к написанию драйвера?

Comment: Вирус хотите сделать? :)

Comment: нет конечно, хотя вероятно информации так мало именно поэтому. У нас корпоративный СЭД в нем выставляются поручения, есть критичные поручения, так вот если сотрудник просрочил выполнение таких поручений то ему должно всплывать уведомление, которое будет его раздражать, раз в час уведомление и закрывается путем открытия данного поручения.

Comment: Распахнуть окно с сообщением на весь экран и сделать его TopMost.

Comment: Скажите, а если вы в срок не выполните поручение по разработке этого софта, вас тоже кто-то будет раздражать раз в час?

Comment: Такое ощущение, что вы пытаетесь техническим методом решить административную проблему. Это так не работает.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> ... софт который полностью блокирует рабочую станцию показывая уведомление.

Переключите пользователя на свой рабочий стол.

Дело в том, что в рамках *оконной станции* (грубо говоря, одного рабочего места) можно иметь несколько *рабочих столов*. Они изолированы друг от друга (у каждого есть свой, независимый, список окон). Более того, текущий стол ведёт себя так, будто других столов не существует. Он захватывает **весь** пользовательский ввод и занимает всю площадь экрана.

*Кстати, окна UAC (запрос повышения привилегий на затемнённом фоне) как раз и создают для своих нужд отдельный рабочий стол, чтобы ни одна программа не могла перехватить вводимый пароль.*

Итак, что надо делать:

1. Сохранить дескриптор текущего рабочего стола, чтобы к нему можно было бы вернуться (сам пользователь сможет это сделать только путём выхода из системы):

   ```
   const HDESK hOld = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());
   ```
2. Создать рабочий стол (в нашем случае с именем `reminder`):

   ```
   const HDESK hNew = CreateDesktop(
       TEXT("reminder"),
       NULL,
       NULL,
       0,
       DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP
       | DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS
       | DESKTOP_READOBJECTS
       | DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW,
       NULL
   );
   ```
3. Переключиться на него, заодно указав, что и все дальнейшие окна мы будем создавать на нём же:

   ```
   SetThreadDesktop(hNew);
   SwitchDesktop(hNew);
   ```

   ВАЖНО: нам нельзя создавать какие-либо окна на основном рабочем столе, иначе `SetThreadDesktop()` [работать не будет](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms686250(v=vs.85).aspx):

   > The `SetThreadDesktop` function will fail if the calling thread has any windows or hooks on its current desktop (unless the `hDesktop` parameter is a handle to the current desktop).
4. Создать диалог с напоминанием. Пусть это будет блокирующий `MessageBox()`:

   ```
   MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Текст напоминания"), TEXT("Напоминание"), MB_ICONWARNING);
   ```
5. Вернуться на исходный рабочий стол:

   ```
   SwitchDesktop(hOld);
   ```
6. По окончании работы рабочий стол надо закрыть во избежание утечки ресурсов:

   ```
   CloseDesktop(hNew);
   ```

---

> Не должны работать никакие <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> и т. д.

По определённым причинам окно диспетчера задач привязывается не к текущему, а к основному рабочему столу. **Поэтому <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Esc</kbd> и даже безопасный <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Delete</kbd> хоть и открывают диспетчер задач, но он станет доступным *только* после возврата на основной рабочий стол, то есть тогда, когда вы и только вы этого захотите.**

---

> ...и фокус должен быть на окне.

Так как наш диалог является единственным на текущем рабочем столе, он автоматически получит фокус.

---

Вот полный и готовый демонстрационный пример:

```
#include <windows.h>

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
    int       nCmdShow
)
{
    const HDESK hOld = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());

    const HDESK hNew = CreateDesktop(
        TEXT("reminder"),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        0,
        DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP
            | DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS
            | DESKTOP_READOBJECTS
            | DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW,
        NULL
    );

    SetThreadDesktop(hNew);
    SwitchDesktop(hNew);

    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Reminder text"), TEXT("Reminder"), MB_ICONWARNING);

    SwitchDesktop(hOld);
    CloseDesktop(hNew);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает.

Comment: Но Ctrl + Alt +Del все таки срабатывает :(

Comment: У Ctrl+Alt+Del вроде тоже собственный рабочий стол? Кстати, @AntonZ, Ctrl+Alt+Del можно запрещать групповыми политиками или просто в реестре, если не ошибаюсь - так что копай в другую сторону.

Answer (score 1):

Сделать универсальной такую программу "легально" - невозможно. Как минимум, столкнетесь с ограничениями прав (в любой нормальной организации все пользователи сидят в домене с очень ограниченными правами.) Соответственно, не сможете программой, запущенной от имени пользователя:

- Вешать хуки
- Управлять процессами
- Управлять сетевой активностью

А вот нелегально - пожалуйста. Все просто:

- Ищете в любом драйвере уязвимость
- Пишете эксплоит
- Распространяете

Получаете новый **WannaCry** :)

Comment: Понятно что все пользователи в домене, это не проблема. Распространять будем доменной политикой со всеми необходимыми правами

Comment: Тогда, не понимаю, какие трудности у Вас возникли... Вашу задачу можно легко реализовать как используя winapi, так и не используя. В самом простом случае - вешайте глобальный обработчик сообщений на окно и ловите все сообщения, которые идут в него. Можно "забиндить" все нужные сочетания клавиш, и, пока запущено ваше приложение, они, например, не будут работать.

Comment: C Ctrl + Alt + Del например почему то не работает

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Del можно запрещать групповыми политиками или просто в реестре, если не ошибаюсь. Так что копай в другую сторону.