# Получить приложение, использующее файл

Tags: c#, процесс

У меня есть путь до картинки, и она используется программой для просмотра картинок, следовательно картинку нельзя удалить, пока не завершен процесс использующей программы. Как с помощью C# можно получить путь использующей программы, имея путь используемой?

Comment: Есть ответ на английском SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3504251/1051621

Answer (score 1):

Пример получения списка процессов, занявших файл можно узнать из официальной документации/примеров кода:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-know-the-process-704839f4

В даном контексте ссылку-ответ считаю приемлимой т.к. маловероятно что она будет удалена и окроме того это официальный источник информации от майкрсофт по языку c#.

Comment: Вот сменит Microsoft в очередной раз схему наименования страниц, и ответ придётся редактировать. Так что, думаю, имеет смысл скопировать код сюда, разбить на мелкие блоки и каждый блок снабдить описанием. Вот пример моего ответа с подобной структурой: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/667340/208074